# Creating key-value paired Object from array with Array.map()?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value, key-value-store

```
const people = ['Peter','Henry','James'];
const unqiue = ['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3'];
let map = unique.map((id, i) => {
    return { name: people[i], id: id };
  });
```

This gives me sth like

```
{
 0: {
  person: 'peter',
  id: ID_A
 },
 1: {
  person: 'simon',
  id: ID_B
 }
}
```

However, I'd like to get back an object keyed by IDSs:

```
{
 ID_A: {
  person: 'peter',
  id: ID_A
 },
 ID_B: {
  person: 'simon',
  id: ID_B
 }
}
```

How could I do this here, I seem not come up with the right thing. I tried this, but doesnt work at all:

```
let map = unique.map((id, i) => {
    return [id] : { name: people[i], id: id };
  });
```

Comment: post the values of `people` and `unique` variable also

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and spread the values of mapping.

```js
var unique = ['ID_A', 'ID_B'],
    people = ['peter', 'simon'],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...unique.map((id, i) => ({ [id]: { name: people[i], id } })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer environments, an option is to map onto `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const map = Object.fromEntries(
  unique.map((id, i) => [id, { name: people[i], id }])
);
```